# Splitting one method into multiple methods - Java Chess

Tags: java, methods, chess

I'm currently trying to build a simple chess piece movement program. I read in the chess movement notation from a text file. The chess notation goes something like this:

plb1 c3  = (p)pawn(l)white moves from position b1(b1) to position c3(c3).
my regex then parses the move.

In the code I match various pieces and print out their various movements. What I want to do is break my *moveBetter()* method into mutliple smaller methods such as a *findPiece()* or *findColor()* methods.

The problem is, everytime I try to break up the methods, they don't work or i'm told i have to make the method static and that breaks it further. **How do I split moveBetter() into multiple methods?**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SuperiorFileIO {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    moveBetter();
}

public static void moveBetter() throws IOException
{
    String piece = " "; //group1
    String color = " "; //group2
    String position = " "; //group3
    String position2 = " "; //group4
    String capture = " "; //group5
    //or 
    String kingPos1 = "";//6
    String kingPos2 = "";//7
    String rookPos1 = "";//8
    String rookPos2 = "";//9

    ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile();     
    String input = readFile.readTextFile("TestMoves");


    Pattern matchingMoves = Pattern.compile("(q|k|b|p|n|r+)(l|d)(\\w\\d) ?(\\w\\d)?([*])?|(\\w\\d) (\\w\\d) (\\w\\d) (\\w\\d)");
    Matcher m1 = matchingMoves.matcher(input);

    while (m1.find())
    {
        //find piece
            if(m1.group(6) != null && m1.group(6).matches("(\\w\\d)")) //castling part 1
                kingPos1 = m1.group(6);
            else if (m1.group(1).equals("q"))
                piece = "Queen";
            else if (m1.group(1).equals("k"))
                piece = "King";
            else if (m1.group(1).equals("b"))
                piece = "Bishop";
            else if (m1.group(1).equals("p"))
                piece = "Pawn";
            else if (m1.group(1).equals("n"))
                piece = "Knight";
            else if (m1.group(1).matches("(q|k|b|p|n|r+)") &&  m1.group(1).equals("r"))
                piece = "Rook";
            else {
                System.out.println("PIECE FAILED");
                piece = "piece Failed";
            }
        //find color
            if(m1.group(7) != null && m1.group(7).matches("(\\w\\d)")) //castling part 2
                kingPos2 = m1.group(7);
            else if(m1.group(2).equals("d"))
                color = "Black";
            else if(m1.group(2).matches("(l|d)") && m1.group(2).equals("l"))
                color = "White";
            else {
                System.out.println("COLOR FAILED");
                piece = "color Failed";
            }
        //set starting position
            if (m1.group(7) != null && m1.group(7).matches("(\\w\\d)") )
            rookPos1 = m1.group(7); //castling part 3
            else
                position = m1.group(3);
        //Castling
            if (m1.group(8) != null && m1.group(9) != null && m1.group(8).matches("(\\w\\d)") && m1.group(9).matches("(\\w\\d)"))
            {
                rookPos1 = m1.group(8);
                rookPos2 = m1.group(9);
                System.out.println("The king moves from " + kingPos1 + " to " + kingPos2 + " while the rook moves from " + rookPos1 + " to " + rookPos2);   
            }
        //if the player does not move // finds a piece
            else if (m1.group(4) == null)
                System.out.println("The " + color + " " + piece + " resides at " + position);           

        //set ending position
            else if (m1.group(4) != null && m1.group(5) == null)
            {
                position2 = m1.group(4);
                System.out.println("The " + color + " " + piece + " moves from " + position + " to " + position2);
            }
        //set ending position and capture
            else if (m1.group(4) != null && m1.group(5) != null)
            {
                //System.out.println("capture occured");
                position2 = m1.group(4);
                capture = m1.group(5); //unused
                System.out.println("The " + color + " " + piece + " moves from " + position + " to " + position2  + " and captures the piece on " + position2);
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("PARSE ERROR");
            }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: what's the problem with making your other method static?

Comment: Don't work how?  Also, the methods have to be static if you want to call them from a static method.

Comment: when i split moveBetter() into different static methods it forces me to make all my other variables static, which then breaks the code. But if everything is under moveBetter(), it all works.

Comment: you have to move the shared variables outside the moveBetter method, otherwise you can't make them static

Comment: I do, but when i use a method like findPiece() that uses those shared variables, i get errors on the findPiece() method, which say to turn that method into a static method. Once I do this, all the variables in this method suddenly require me to change all their modifiers to static.

Comment: changing all of the shared variables to static then breaks the code.

Comment: what you mean by breaks the code?

Comment: I started to refactor your code, but that super regex makes breaking the pieces apart nearly impossible.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `movePiece` from your static `main` method. define a `ChessEngine` class or something, instantiate one in your main method, and then have that `ChessEngine` object handle all of the logic. Then you can split up your method as suggested in the other answers/comments.

Comment: he/she seems to be a beginner, I doubt he/she is ready to understand anything of what you said

Comment: Got it. Thanks, that was the easy fix I was completely missing. Time to re-delve into all the java i forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    findPiece();
    findColor();
}

private static void findPiece()
{
    //Code
}

private static void findColor()
{
    //Code
}
```

Method visibility can be private or public depending on how you want to use it, I would prefer private for these methods.

findPiece() :

```
while(m1.find())
{
    if(m1.group(6) != null && m1.group(6).matches("(\\w\\d)")) //castling part 1
        kingPos1 = m1.group(6);
    else if (m1.group(1).equals("q"))
        piece = "Queen";
    else if (m1.group(1).equals("k"))
        piece = "King";
    else if (m1.group(1).equals("b"))
        piece = "Bishop";
    else if (m1.group(1).equals("p"))
        piece = "Pawn";
    else if (m1.group(1).equals("n"))
        piece = "Knight";
    else if (m1.group(1).matches("(q|k|b|p|n|r+)") &&  m1.group(1).equals("r"))
        piece = "Rook";
    else {
        System.out.println("PIECE FAILED");
        piece = "piece Failed";
    }
}
```

Pretty much the same for the other methods, loop and copy paste the part you want to execute.
Though if the code in each method is needed in another method, then splitting it will not work simply

Comment: yeah I've tried this, it still doesn't work. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong, the code wants me to add static modifiers to everything. I feel like this is a really simple fix but i'm missing something

Comment: Well your not. You cannot reference non static methods or variables in a static one. Every method you use inside your static main method that was created in the same class but outside the main method must be static. If you don't want to use static, you need to create a different class with all the above methods, and in your main method create the object of the class and use the methods normally

Answer (score 0):

Consider this basic example:

```
public static void moveBetter() throws IOException
{
    String piece = "pluto";
    piece = "goofy";
}
```

in order to split this in two method you have to:

1.extract the variable and put it outside moveBetter

```
string piece;

public static void moveBetter() throws IOException
{
    piece = "pluto";
    piece = "goofy";
}
```

2.define the variable as static since a static method (like moveBetter) can't access a non static variable or a non static method

```
static string piece;
```

3.create a the new method and move the code inside it. remember the new method must be static too in order to be accessed by moveBetter

```
string static piece;

public static void moveBetter() throws IOException
{
    piece = "pluto";
    assignGoofy();
}

public static void assignGoofy()
{
    piece = "goofy";
}
```